# CodeChef Error in submission(Not asking the solution)

Tags: c++, c++11

I completed my solution for SUMTRIAN i.e. https://www.codechef.com/problems/SUMTRIAN

When I submit, it gives me wrong answer. I am definite that I have formatting problems and I am not sure how do I print my answer for that.

here is the code -

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{int w;
      cin>>w;

   for(int x=0;x<w;x++)   
   {
      int a[105][105],n;
      cin>>n;
      int i,j;
      for( i=0;i<n;i++)
            for( j=0;j<=i;j++)
                  cin>>a[i][j];

      i = n-1;
      j = n-1;
      int sumarr[n],sum=0;
      for(int z=0;z<n;z++)
      {
            i=n-1;
            j=n-1-z;
            sum=0;
            do{
                  sum+=a[i][j];
//                  cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
                  i--;j--;

                  if(j<0)
                        j++;

            }while(i>=0 && j>=0);
            sumarr[z]=sum;
//            cout<<endl;
      }
//      cout<<sumarr[1];
      cout<<*max_element(sumarr,sumarr+n)<<"\n";
   }
}
```

Any help would be great! :D 
Thanks in advance !!:)

Comment: VLAs are not standard C++, use `std::vector` instead if you need a dynamic array or `std::array` for a fixed-size array.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury the code works fine on my compiler. GIves the proper output.

Comment: It may work on your compiler (GCC supports VLAs) but it is still not standard C++ so you shouldn't use them.

Comment: Tried that. Didnt work out. Anything else? :P

Comment: 1) We don't know the internals of these coding websites, so it is futile to ask here on SO questions concerning them.  2) Instead of posting the code verbatim, take out the input routines and hard-code the data you claim "works"  3) Never use VLA's for this and always use `std::vector`.  Why?  a) It is standard C++, and b) you can easily test if you're going out of bounds by calling `vector::at()`.  A VLA has **none** of these advantages.  4) `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`  Garbage.  Please include the right standard headers, not this nonsense.